# Alternative to get.hist.quote

Tags: r, function

```
library(tseries)
library(zoo)
library(forecast)
library(FinTS)
library(rugarch)
DJI.data<- get.hist.quote(instrument="^DJI", start= "2010-01-01", 

end="2015-07-23", quote="AdjClose", provider= "yahoo", compression="d", retclass="zoo")
```

did not work....I get, get.hist.quote function not found. How can I fix this? thnx

Comment: It works for me.  Try it again just in case there was a problem with the backend site just at the time you tried it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to consider trying the Quantmod package for its getSymbols function. I tried the following and it worked

```
getSymbols("^DJI", from = "2010-01-01", to = "2015-07-23")
```